# create websocket server in oracle adf 11g project

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

I am need help to create websocket server on a adf application in jdeveloper 11g and I'm sorry if my question looks non relevant or too easy for some of you.

my main question is :

**How to create websocket server on a adf application in jdeveloper 11g**

Thanks all for reading and hope for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets are supported from Weblogic 12c only.
You may consider an upgrade.